# unable to start libvirt

Tags: virtualization, 17.04

and I may have made things worse with rm -rf /var/run/libvirtd.pid

```
root@ts:/home/t# libvirtd
2017-05-28 07:48:19.090+0000: 5473: info : libvirt version: 2.5.0, package: 3ubuntu5 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Tue, 21 Mar 2017 08:02:37 +0100)
2017-05-28 07:48:19.090+0000: 5473: info : hostname: ts
2017-05-28 07:48:19.090+0000: 5473: error : virPidFileAcquirePath:422 : Failed to acquire pid file '/var/run/libvirtd.pid': Resource temporarily unavailable
root@ts:/home/t# status libvirtd
status: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
root@ts:/home/t# ps ax | grep libvirtd
 2595 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/libvirtd
 5562 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto libvirtd
root@ts:/home/t# kill -9 2595
root@ts:/home/t# rm -rf /var/run/libvirtd.pid
root@ts:/home/t# status libvirtd
status: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
root@ts:/home/t# libvirtd
2017-05-28 07:50:11.363+0000: 5786: info : libvirt version: 2.5.0, package: 3ubuntu5 (Christian Ehrhardt <christian.ehrhardt@canonical.com> Tue, 21 Mar 2017 08:02:37 +0100)
2017-05-28 07:50:11.363+0000: 5786: info : hostname: ts
2017-05-28 07:50:11.363+0000: 5786: error : qemuMonitorJSONCheckError:387 : internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'query-cpu-definitions': The command query-cpu-definitions has not been found
2017-05-28 07:50:11.363+0000: 5786: warning : virQEMUCapsLogProbeFailure:4441 : Failed to probe capabilities for /usr/bin/qemu-system-alpha: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'query-cpu-definitions': The command query-cpu-definitions has not been found
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error as this one :

> error : qemuMonitorJSONCheckError:387 : internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'query-cpu-definitions': The command query-cpu-definitions has not been found

I solved it by enabling the virtualization options in the computer bios as well as disabling the secure boot option.

Hope it was any help.